# Using MySQL with flask

Tags: python, mysql, flask

Iam trying to import MySQL into flask for a python web app I'm building.
I have tried everything:

```
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
from flask.ext.mysql import MySQL
from flask_mysql import MySQL
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
```

I have flask-mysql installed as well as flask-mysqldb
But no matter what I do I alwase get the code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 2, in <module>
    from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
ImportError: No module named flaskext.mysql
```

What do I do?

Comment: Did you actually install any of those libraries?

Comment: yes I ran 'pip install flask-mysql', 'pip install flask-mysqldb'

Answer (score 0):

From your question only, I ran the same - 
`pip install flask-mysql` command and then did -

```
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
```

This works for me.
Not sure why it is not working in your system. I can see that this package is installed on the path - */usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flaskext*

And my **sys.path** contains */usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/* . May be you can also check the output of sys.path and see if it contains the path to the flaskext.

Comment: how do check the output of sys.path

Comment: open python on cmd or terminal (depending on your OS) and run - *import sys* and then *sys.path*

Comment: I get this:  ['', '/Users/ajs/Documents', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python36.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages']

Comment: Can you search if flaskext is installed on correct path or not. Use this command and check what is gives - *sudo find / -name flaskext*

Comment: Also, you have Flask and MySQL installed? Right?

Comment: yep everything is installed

Answer (score 0):

Using **MySQL** in **flask python web-framework** is really easy.
I hope you have install **pip dependency and set it to path variable**

Go to console & run this command

```
pip install flask-mysql
```

the following command will install the dependency :=> flask-mysql

now go to main script mainly app.py
and add this

```
from flask import Flask,jsonify
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
app=Flask(__name__)
mysql = MySQL()
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = '******'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'shop'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'localhost'
mysql.init_app(app)
conn = mysql.connect()
cursor =conn.cursor()
```

and if you need to do any **Database operation at any end point** do this

```
#let suppose shop is database and product is table
    @app.route("/path/to/your/endpoint")
    def getDataFromDb():
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM product")
        data=cursor.fetchall()
        return jsonify({'status':200,'data':data})
```

- Please use db and table according to your requirement
  You will be good to go.